# Java swing animate swing components without performance loss

Tags: java, swing, animation

**Solution:**

Yes it is wrong. Never, never, never, NEVER read in files/images within a painting method. This method must be blindingly fast and must involve painting only, and doing this, reading in a file, will needlessly slow down your GUI to a crawl. And why do this? You can read the image in once in a constructor or method and then reuse the image object in paintComponent as many times as needed.

As an aside, you're probably better off obtaining the image as a resource and not a file.

Thanks, Hovercraft Full Of Eels

---

I am creating a very simple version of 'Fruit Ninja'. A game where some fruit flies onto the screen and the user has to cut it in two.

I am using a JLabel with ImageIcon for the fruit. I use a swing Timer for movement.

It works great, with animations too, but here is the tricky part. When I add a background image, the animations are verry laggy.

The question is: How can I add a background image, while the swing animations won't lose performance?

I added some code below.

Tim

My JPanel where I draw my background image:

```
public class PlayingField extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public PlayingField()
{
    this.setBounds(0, 50, 500, 500);
    this.setLayout(null);       
}

@Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/assets/background.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {

    }
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

The objects I'm drawing on them are just simple JLabels with ImageIcons.

I have a timer that handles the animation:

```
public class GameTimer extends javax.swing.Timer implements ActionListener {

GameController gameController;

public GameTimer(GameController gameController) {
    super(delay, null);
    this.addActionListener(this);
    this.gameController = gameController;

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{

        gameController.moveObject();
}

}
```

and last but not least the code that moves the object:

```
public void moveObject()
{

    activeObject.setPositionY((activeObjectView.getPositionY()+1));
    playingField.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Yes to seeing code, especially how you're adding the background image. My fear is that you may be reading the image into your program within paint or paintComponent or something horrendous like that. Code is almost always necessary for such questions, and best would be if you could create and post your [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah, I did do it in the paintComponent override. Is that wrong? Could you please point me in the right direction? I added some code! Thanks!

Comment: Don't load the image in the `paintComponent` method!!!!1111 Load it **once** in the constructor, and only **paint** it in the `paintComponent` method. Then, most likely, your performance problems will already vanish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is wrong. Never, never, never, ***NEVER*** read in files/images within a painting method. This method must be blindingly fast and must involve painting only, and doing this, reading in a file, will needlessly slow down your GUI to a crawl. And why do this? You can read the image in once in a constructor or method and then reuse the image object in paintComponent as many times as needed.

As an aside, you're probably better off obtaining the image as a resource and not a file.

Comment: While reading your comment I'm literally slapping myself in the face.That was so obvious, I don't have any clue why I didn't see this in the first place. I'll check out if that's the problem and update my post! Thanks

Comment: Yep, it did work. Thanks so much, again! You really helped me out! Will take a look into resources!